# To check if the first child node is a processing instruction or not

Tags: xslt, processing-instruction

I want a code snippet to check if the first child node is a processing instruction or not?

For example :

```
<caml:Author>
<?PI-start data="processing instruction"?>
<caml:Leg> test data </caml:Leg>
</caml:Author>
```

In the above example the first child node of caml:Author tag is a processing instruction. How can I find if the first child node is a processing instruction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering that you could also get comments or text nodes (the first child node of  in your example is a text node), then if caml:Author is my current node, I would use the following to address the children:

```
  test="(processing-instruction() | *)[1][self::processing-instruction()]"
```

The result is true if the first of the processing-instruction and element children is a processing-instruction.

Comment: Thank you, Ken. It worked. I understand that "(processing-instruction() | *)[1]" will check if the first node is processing instruction or not but can you explain me the what does "self::processing-instruction" do ?

Comment: @AshokAmbrose - `(processing-instruction()|*)[1]` matches the first processing instruction or element. The `[self::processing-instruction()]` predicate verifies it is a processing instruction and not an element. However, I think the white-space in `caml:Author` is insignificant so `node()[1][self::processing-instruction()]` should still work.

Comment: Ignore my comment about the white-space above. That's only true if you use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` which I almost always do.

Comment: Interestingly, I've never included <xsl:strip-space> in any of my production work.  I tell my students that that is risky for mixed content and advise them not to use it either (though I suppose it would be safe if you knew your document was only element content, as OASIS Universal Business Language is as an example).  I figure it is better to teach good techniques that work whether insignificant white-space is present or not, hence the expression I wrote.  Consider the XML `<name><given>Ashok</given> <surname>Ambrose</surname></name>`.  The space between would be lost yet it is significant.